# Can I live outside Canada and get paid into my Canadian bank account for freelance work?

Tags: income-tax, canada, non-resident

I live outside Canada and have declared non-resident status to the CRA. I haven't declared income or paid taxes for the last 4 years, or even stepped foot in Canada for the same duration. I do have an active bank account there.

Now I have started some freelance work and most websites don't recognize where I live as a location for payment options, but Canadian bank accounts are available. Can I receive payment for my freelance work into my Canadian bank account and still remain a non-resident?

Answer (score 1):

You can actually have and use your Canadian bank account even if you live outside of the country. You will still remain a non-resident even if money is received into this account.

Some people from the US actually have a Canadian bank account.

What I don't know is what your tax liability will be or if the bank will report your deposits to the government. This may depend on the amount deposited.

Comment: I live in the US and considering to open a Bank Account in Canada. Whether i am eligible to have a Bank Account in Canada without living or visiting Canada?